# AWS appsync and push notification

Tags: push-notification, ionic3, chat, aws-appsync

I have built an ionic application and now I want to add the chat functionality to it.
I was looking into different technologies that can be used to implement a chat.
I considered using the app sync and my only concern so far, is that if I can see which users are not online at the moment of message sent event, So I can send a push notification.

Or, if the app sync handle this out of the box and send notification as well?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Take a look [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#delta-sync).DeltaSync allows you to perform automatic synchronization with an AWS AppSync GraphQL server. The client will perform reconnection, exponential backoff etc

Answer (score 2):

Hey this is a great question. The short answer is that the AppSync SDK does not handle presence tracking out of the box but you can implement this feature yourself without too much hassle.

Off of the top of my head, one way to do this is to create a DynamoDB table "ActiveUsers". Enable DynamoDB TTL (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) on the table (using some "timestamp" attribute) and use some unique user attribute such as username or userId as the table's Partition Key.

Then from AppSync create a **Mutation.ping** mutation that makes a **PutItem** call like this:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        "userId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.identity.username)
    },
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson({
      timestamp: $util.time.nowEpochSeconds() + 300 # some amount of time
    })
}
```

From your client you would then call that mutation every N seconds, at start up time, or based on some other criteria. In the case where the user has good connection, have the application call another mutation **Mutation.goOffline** that deletes the record from DynamoDB whenever the application is being closed. If the user does not have good connection and therefore the client is unable to send the **Mutation.goOffline** mutation, the DynamoDB TTL can kick in an clean up for us.

To push updates, for when someone goes online or offline, to connected clients you can make a subscription **Subscription.onActiveChange** with this directive **@aws_subscribe(mutations: ["publishActiveChange"])**. Then also define the **Mutation.publishActiveChange** mutation and have it return the user id and activity status of a user. To finish the picture, you would create a DynamoDB stream that calls a lambda function that calls the **Mutation.publishActiveChange** mutation that whever an object is either deleted or (newly) created in DynamoDB publish the message.

You could alternatively subscribe to the **ping** and **goOffline** mutations and not bother with the DynamoDB stream and lambda function, but this approach will not publish a subscription when the client device goes offline before calling **goOffline**. The TTL will still work but the device will have to get notified via a subsequent query. Depending on your requirements, this works pretty well and has the bonus of being less complex.

One other thing to consider is that DynamoDB TTL is not guaranteed to happen immediately but in practice performs pretty well (within a few minutes). But, really large tables will likely see a little lag.

Comment: Why should we go hardly like this? @mparis
I think we should use IoT core service to detect the user offline status and use AppSync by combining with SNS for specifically push notification feature.

What do you think?

Comment: convert your mutation resolver to pipeline and make the last one have a lambda datasource.  In that lambda function use the apn library to configure and send your push notification. https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn  been using if for sometime now and works very well.  I imagine there is a similar library for android push notifications although I am not using that.